# RPy2: LookupError when calling R function 'DEoptim' in python

Tags: r, python-2.7, rpy2, robjects

I've finally got RPy2 working on my Windows 7 computer with Python 2.7.8 and R 3.10.1. I want to call the R function 'DEoptim' which did not come with my R installation however the package has been downloaded via the R Repository and is working in R.

When I do this:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
dea = robjects.r['DEoptim']
```

I get the following error:

```
LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a882c24e8623> in <module>()
----> 1 dea = robjects.r['DEoptim']

C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.pyc in __getitem__(self, item)
    224 
    225     def __getitem__(self, item):
--> 226         res = _globalenv.get(item)
    227         res = conversion.ri2ro(res)
    228         res.__rname__ = item

LookupError: 'DEoptim' not found
```

Which seems to make sense. Python is trying to find this package however it is not there. When importing this package in R I can see this that it is located at: `C:/Users/Patrick/Documents/R/win-library/3.1`.

Is there any way that I can call this function from python? I've looked around for a good DE optimization package in python and found insyred however using the DEoptim package from R is much easier. Also, there are a lot of other R packages not in the standard library that would be great to have around once in a while

Comment: You need to the [import the package](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/robjects_rpackages.html) just like you do in R.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely need to load the relevant R package. The rpy2 function `importr` provide a simple interface to R packages.

Comment: Simple enough! I guess I was looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that solved the problem for me in case anyone gets stuck or doesn't take enough time to read the documentation (like me..)

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
dea = importr('DEoptim', lib_loc="C:/Users/Patrick/Documents/R/win-library/3.1")
```